# SQLCommand throw new NotImplementedException();

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi i am trying to store the value of a group of textboxes into a sql database, I have created the database and written the sql script. I have created the connection to sql database from my project when the script runs i get the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in >PLUPROG.exe
>
> Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

Casued by.

```
public static implicit operator SqlCommand(Sqlcommand v)
    {

         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

The code for my SQL script is

```
private void btnAddPlu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = PluProg; Integrated Security = True"))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Departments VALUES (@Name, @Type, @SubDept)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new Sqlcommand(query, sqlConn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = cbDeptName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = cbDeptType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDept", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = cbSubDept.Text;
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch ()
```

Comment: How is this different than [your last question?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39800963/1070452)

Comment: If you're having so much trouble, just do it manually. There's nothing complicated about transferring a datatable to SQL and back. In the time it took you to wait for an answer then ask the question again, you could've written manual transfers 100 times over.

Comment: I am importing from a series of textboxes and not an external file. The only relation to the two are the SQL scripts, these scripts run on the database in SQL management studio absolutely fine.

Comment: Well, the code above will always throw a not implemented exception, because it's a command. Literally "Throw new NotImplemented Exception();" Take that line out and viola - no more exception

Comment: Thanks that line in the SqlCommand file was automatic created, not sure why if it will create the error i now recive

CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'PLUPROG.Sqlcommand' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' PLUPROG

Comment: This is shown on the line 
    SqlCommand cmd = new Sqlcommand(query, sqlConn);

Comment: That entire `operator SqlCommand` method is wrong. I've been using `SqlCommand` for years and have never had a method like that “automatic created”? Are you using some kind of code tool like Entity Framework? There's something important you're not telling us.

Comment: I do have Entity Framework but I don't believe it is being used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you're asking, but I feel bad that you've asked twice and clearly haven't figured out anything. Take a look at this and see if something answers your question. The following is not optimized/generalized - just basic stuff for you to see what's what and improve on in your own way.

```
 public SqlConnection getConn()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(getConnString());
    }
    public string getConnString()
    {
        return @"Data Source=lily.arvixe.com;Initial Catalog=WM_Crawler;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={myUser};Password={MyPass};Connection Timeout=7000";
    }
 //This is how you flush a DataTable
 public  void saveDataTable(string tableName, DataTable table)
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))//, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
            {
                // my DataTable column names match my SQL Column names, so I simply made this loop. However if your column names don't match, just pass in which datatable name matches the SQL column name in Column Mappings
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                   bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, "["+col.ColumnName+"]");
                }
                bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 8000;
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
                bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
                //bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += BulkCopy_SqlRowsCopied;
                //bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 10000;
               bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    //this is how you select one field from one row
    public object scalar(string sql)
    {
        object ret;
        using (SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                com.CommandText = sql;
                ret = com.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
        return ret;
    }
    //this is how you execute a command using SQL string (admin functions)
    public void nonQuery(string sql)
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using(SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                com.CommandText = sql;
                com.CommandTimeout = 5900;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();

        }

    }
    // This is how you execute a query using a predefined, parameterized command (user input)
    public void nonQuery_With_Command(SqlCommand com)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (com)
            {
                com.Connection = conn;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();

        }

    }
    //this is how you execute several commands under one connection (sql or stored procedure)
    public void nonQuery_List_Command(List<SqlCommand> comList)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            foreach (SqlCommand com in comList)
            {
               using (com)
                {
                    com.Connection = conn;
                    try
                    {
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch(Exception n1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(n1.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(com.Parameters[1].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
                }
            conn.Close();

        }

    }
    //This returns column names from a specific table (example of a datareader)
    private List<string> get_Column_Names(string tableName)
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using(SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                com.CommandText = "select column_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_Name = '" + tableName + "'";
                com.CommandTimeout = 600;
                SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    ret.Add(Convert.ToString(read[0]));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return ret;
    }
    //This converts a reader to a class using fields. It is not optimized and is inefficient, but allows you to see what's happening. Yu can optimize it yourself
    public static object[] sql_Reader_To_Type(Type t, SqlDataReader r)
    {
        List<object> ret = new List<object>();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            FieldInfo[] f = t.GetFields();
            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
            {
                string thisType = f[i].FieldType.ToString();
                switch (thisType)
                {
                    case "System.String":

                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToString(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    case "System.Int16":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt16(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    case "System.Int32":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt32(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    case "System.Int64":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt64(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    case "System.Double":
                        double th;
                            if (r[f[i].Name].GetType() == typeof(DBNull))
                            {
                                th = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                th = Convert.ToDouble(r[f[i].Name]);
                            }
                        }
                        try { f[i].SetValue(o, th); }
                        catch (Exception e1)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("can't convert " + f[i].Name + " to double - value =" + th);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "System.Boolean":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt32(r[f[i].Name]) == 1 ? true : false);
                        break;
                    case "System.DateTime":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToDateTime(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Missed data type in sql select ");

                }
            }
            ret.Add(o);

        }
        return ret.ToArray();


    }
    //these are basic (rudimentary) ways of converting class to DataTable
    public static DataTable create_DataTable_From_Generic_Class(Type t)
    {
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        PropertyInfo[] pI = t.GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < pI.Length; i++)
        {

            DataColumn dC = new DataColumn(pI[i].Name, pI[i].PropertyType);
            d.Columns.Add(dC);

        }
        return d;
    }
    public static object[] Create_Datatable_Row_From_Generic_Class(Type t, object instance, DataTable dt)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] p = t.GetProperties();
        object[] ret = new object[dt.Columns.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var temp = t.GetProperty(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);
            ret[i] = temp.GetValue(instance);

        }
       return ret;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you i will give this a try and report back I made it work on a  very basic previous program and tried that code but couldnt get it to work,